# Inserting a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone could give me some guidance here. My situation is this:

One worksheet with 100 rows of data in a table
Each cell in Column A holds one of two values - either CSv1 or CSv2
Column B holds a specific case_number

I want to insert a column at position 4 (Column D) with the label 'Caselink'
In location D2 I am trying to insert a hyperlink that builds off A2 and B2 where the link is dependent on the value in both. (they go to two different sites depending on column A). Then to populate down with relative location to row numbers... Here is what I have so far, but it gives me an error on the 'Else' statement saying I havean 'Else without If'.

If I take out the else statement and follow-on formula, and leave only the first If formula, it will populate all cells in the D column with the link for the CSv1 value.

Thoughts?

```
Sub InsertHyperlink_EscFeedback()

    With ActiveSheet
        .ListObjects(1).Name = "Drilldown"
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim target_table As ListObject
    Set target_table = ws.ListObjects("Drilldown")
    Dim activeTable As String
    activeTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name  

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Activate
    Selection.ListObject.ListColumns.Add Position:=4

    Range("D1") = "CaseLink"
    Range("D2").Select
    If Range("A2").Value = "CSv2" Then _
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=HYPERLINK(""https://open.companytest.com/fredsfakeurl.aspx?conv=""&[@[case_number]]&""&st="",[@[case_number]])"

    Else

        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=HYPERLINK(""https://open.companytest.com/janesfakeurl.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&help=""&[@[case_number]]&""&st="",[@[case_number]])"

       Range("A1").Select
    End If

    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies - to clarify, the [case_number] is the header for Column B

Comment: Remove the ` _` after `Then`... that's the line continuation character, meaning you're using the single-line form of `If... Then`, which would mean you can't then use `Else`.

Comment: That helped to get rid of the error - thank you. But now it seems to actually ignore the Column A condition of either value. It seems to apply only the first value regardless of what is in column A

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You'll need to adjust the column header for the first column (CSv1/2)

```
Sub InsertHyperlink_EscFeedback()

    Const LINK1 = "HYPERLINK(""https://open.companytest.com/fredsfakeurl.aspx?conv=""&[@[case_number]]&""&st="",[@[case_number]])"
    Const LINK2 = "HYPERLINK(""https://open.companytest.com/janesfakeurl.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&help=""&[@[case_number]]&""&st="",[@[case_number]])"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject, lc As ListColumn

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
    lo.Name = "Drilldown"
    Set lc = lo.ListColumns.Add(Position:=4)
    lc.Name = "CaseLink"

    lc.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF([@[link_type]]=""CSv2""," & LINK1 & "," & LINK2 & ")"

    lo.Range.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. the information was very helpful - As Column A only had an option between two values I was able to fifure out how to do it with a simple single IF formula like this:

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-3]=""CSv1"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.companytest.com/fredsfakeurl.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="",RC[-2]),RC[-2]),HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.companytest.com/janesfakeurl.aspx?conv="",RC[-2]),RC[-2]))"

Answer (score 0):

As there were only two values possible in Column A, I was able to resolve with a simple single line IF statement:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-3]=""CSv1"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.companytest.com/fredsfakeurl.aspx?rdx=9992956J43211&conv="",RC[-2]),RC[-2]),HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://open.companytest.com/janesfakeurl.aspx?conv="",RC[-2]),RC[-2]))"